How can I perform bitwise operations in python exactly how javascript would?
I am trying to write the following javascript function in python
exports.hash = u => {
    u += 0xe91aaa35;
    u ^= u >>> 16;
    u += u << 8;
    u ^= u >>> 4;
    let a  = ( u + ( u << 2 ) ) >>> 19;
    return a ^ hashAdjust[ ( u >>> 8 ) & 0x1ff ];
};

Initially I came up with the following
def hash(u):
    u += 0xe91aaa35
    u ^= u >> 16
    u += u << 8
    u ^= u >> 4
    a = (u + (u << 2)) >> 19
    return a ^ hashAdjust[(u >> 8) & 0x1ff]

however I noticed the two functions return different results for large integer inputs. I did some debugging and realised its because javascript and python handle integers differently. Whilst python has unlimited precision integers, javascript uses 32 (signed) bit integers, meaning the maximum integer it can handle is 2^31 - 1, and the minimum is -(2^31 - 1), if an operation results in an integer exceeding these limits, the result gets truncated. I will be honest and admit I dont understand this completely, so I would appreciate if someone could explain this a bit more for me
my main question was how can I create a function for each of the bitwise operators (xor, left shift and right shift) used above to avoid this difference. I found one already for xor  which works perfectly and kind of understood (again, would appreciate an explanation).
Edit: here is the value of hashAdjust alongside a test run in javascript of what I am expecting


hashAdjust = [
    0, 5628, 7017, 1298, 2918, 2442, 8070, 6383, 6383, 7425, 2442, 5628, 8044, 7425, 3155, 6383,
    2918, 7452, 1533, 6849, 5586, 7452, 7452, 1533, 2209, 6029, 2794, 3509, 7992, 7733, 7452, 131,
    6029, 4491, 1814, 7452, 6110, 3155, 7077, 6675, 532, 1334, 7555, 5325, 3056, 1403, 1403, 3969,
    4491, 1403, 7592, 522, 8070, 1403, 0, 1905, 3584, 2918, 922, 3304, 6675, 0, 7622, 7017,
    3210, 2139, 1403, 5225, 0, 3969, 7992, 5743, 5499, 5499, 5345, 7452, 522, 305, 3056, 7017,
    7017, 2139, 1338, 3056, 7452, 1403, 6799, 3204, 3290, 4099, 1814, 2191, 4099, 5743, 1570, 1334,
    7363, 1905, 0, 6799, 4400, 1480, 6029, 1905, 0, 7525, 2028, 2794, 131, 7646, 3155, 4986,
    1858, 2442, 7992, 1607, 3584, 4986, 706, 6029, 5345, 7622, 6322, 5196, 1905, 6847, 218, 1785,
    0, 4099, 2981, 6849, 4751, 3950, 7733, 3056, 5499, 4055, 6849, 1533, 131, 5196, 2918, 3879,
    5325, 2794, 6029, 0, 0, 322, 7452, 6178, 2918, 2320, 6675, 3056, 6675, 1533, 6029, 1428,
    2280, 2171, 6788, 7452, 3325, 107, 4262, 311, 5562, 7857, 6110, 2139, 4942, 4600, 1905, 0,
    3083, 5345, 7452, 6675, 0, 6112, 4099, 7017, 1338, 6799, 2918, 1232, 3584, 522, 6029, 5325,
    1403, 6759, 6849, 508, 6675, 2987, 7745, 6870, 896, 7452, 1232, 4400, 12, 2981, 3850, 4491,
    6849, 0, 6675, 747, 4491, 7525, 6675, 7452, 7992, 6921, 7323, 6849, 3056, 1199, 2139, 6029,
    6029, 190, 4351, 7891, 4400, 7134, 1533, 1194, 3950, 6675, 5345, 6383, 7622, 131, 1905, 2883,
    6383, 1533, 5345, 2794, 4303, 1403, 0, 1338, 2794, 992, 4871, 6383, 4099, 2794, 3889, 6184,
    3304, 1905, 6383, 3950, 3056, 522, 1810, 3975, 7622, 7452, 522, 6799, 5866, 7084, 7622, 6528,
    2798, 7452, 1810, 7907, 642, 5345, 1905, 6849, 6675, 7745, 2918, 4751, 3229, 2139, 6029, 5207,
    6601, 2139, 7452, 5890, 1428, 5628, 7622, 2139, 3146, 2400, 578, 941, 7672, 1814, 3210, 1533,
    4491, 12, 2918, 1900, 7425, 2794, 2987, 3465, 1377, 3822, 3969, 3210, 859, 5499, 6878, 1377,
    3056, 4027, 8065, 8065, 5207, 4400, 4303, 3210, 3210, 0, 6675, 357, 5628, 5512, 1905, 3452,
    1403, 7646, 859, 6788, 3210, 2139, 378, 5663, 7733, 870, 0, 4491, 4813, 2110, 578, 2139,
    3056, 4099, 1905, 1298, 4672, 2191, 3950, 5499, 3969, 4974, 6323, 6029, 7414, 6383, 0, 4974,
    3210, 795, 4099, 131, 5345, 5345, 6576, 1810, 1621, 4400, 2918, 1905, 2442, 2679, 6322, 7452,
    2110, 1403, 6383, 2653, 5132, 6856, 7841, 2794, 6110, 2028, 6675, 7425, 6999, 7441, 6029, 183,
    6675, 4400, 859, 1403, 2794, 5985, 5345, 1533, 322, 4400, 1227, 5890, 4474, 4491, 3574, 8166,
    6849, 7086, 5345, 5345, 5459, 3584, 6675, 3969, 7579, 8044, 2295, 2577, 1480, 5743, 3304, 5499,
    330, 4303, 6863, 3822, 4600, 4751, 5628, 3822, 2918, 6675, 2400, 6663, 1403, 6849, 6029, 3145,
    6110, 3210, 747, 3229, 3056, 2918, 7733, 330, 4055, 7322, 5628, 2987, 3056, 1905, 2903, 669,
    5325, 2845, 4099, 5225, 6283, 4099, 5000, 642, 4055, 5345, 8034, 2918, 1041, 5769, 7051, 1538,
    2918, 3366, 608, 4303, 3921, 0, 2918, 1905, 218, 6687, 5963, 859, 3083, 2987, 896, 5056,
    1905, 2918, 4415, 7966, 7646, 2883, 5628, 7017, 8029, 6528, 4474, 6322, 5562, 6669, 4610, 7006
];

hash = u => {
    u += 0xe91aaa35;
    u ^= u >>> 16;
    u += u << 8;
    u ^= u >>> 4;
    let a  = ( u + ( u << 2 ) ) >>> 19;
    return a ^ this.hashAdjust[ ( u >>> 8 ) & 0x1ff ];
};

console.log(this.hash(104553157))




What is hashAdjust?

@mplungjan it is an array of integers

@mplungjan I apologise, I should have given you the value of hashAdjust, I have included this alongside a test run in the edit above. I tested your function for the same input and got the following "Original u: 104553157
After addition: -279575302
After first XOR: 279571372
After left shift and add: -1164601428
After second XOR: 1094504150
Value a: 10438
Final result: 10188", the final result should match the one above (7893), so something is wrong, no idea what though

It's complicated to get a 1:1 implementation. For example JavaScript has two kinds of right shifts: Signed right shift (>>): Preserves the sign (fills with the sign bit) and Unsigned right shift (>>>): Fills with zeros, effectively treating the value as an unsigned integer. Python, only has one type of right shift: Arithmetic right shift (>>): which works like the signed right shift in JavaScript.

@mplungjan yes I had seen that too, but wasnt sure that would impact the function for the range of inputs I'd be using this function for. Is it impossible to implement perfectly then?

you rely on bogus JS functioning here, not a reliable approach, since all operands are 32 bit max

@AlexanderNenashev the javascript function was written by someone else however I need to match it exactly in python, as the rest of the system relies of this single function/

you could use numpy and force signed 32 bit integers.

The >>> operator in JavaScript performs an unsigned bitwise right shift, which has no native equivalent in Python. Instead, you can convert the given integer to a C-compatible 32-bit unsigned integer with ctypes.c_uint32 so that performing a >> operation with it will result in an unsigned bitwise right shift:
import ctypes

def hash(u):
    u = ctypes.c_uint32(u)
    u.value += 0xe91aaa35
    u.value ^= u.value >> 16
    u.value += u.value << 8
    u.value ^= u.value >> 4
    a = ctypes.c_uint32(u.value + (u.value << 2)).value >> 19
    return a ^ hashAdjust[(u.value >> 8) & 0x1ff]

print(hash(104553157)) # outputs 7893

Demo: https://ideone.com/B3khxi
